Beats not detected in clear signal
I am trying to identify beats and tempo to differentiate between signals with librosa. However, when I was exploring the data I found that I cannot find the beats for my fourth audio (audio 4) despite the beeps being clearly spaced (as seen in the waveform). A note about audio 3: it is a constant beep, but the one I am trying to understand better is audio 4.
The code I use to do so is as follows.
onset_env = librosa.onset.onset_strength(y=y, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length, aggregate=np.median)

tempo, beats = librosa.beat.beat_track(onset_envelope=onset_env, sr=sr, hop_length=512)

diff = np.diff(librosa.frames_to_time(beats, sr=sr)).mean() #calculate time between beeps




Have you tried using the debugger? You can step through and see what Librosa is actually doing, and see where it fails.

I am not sure it is failing per se. I think the signal characteristics make them not spot the beats. I am looking how to process the signal so that it is detected. For instance, if I use np.mean instead of np.median as aggregate function for onset_strength, it does detect the beats but then for the rest I get wrong tempo. I need a general solution because I will not know the type of sound upon detection.

I’m not saying it’s “failing” as in buggy or ill-written. It is however, like you just said, failing to detect the beats on that particular signal. Stepping through and debugging will help identify where in the signal processing chain these characteristics make it fail. From there you might be able to derive pre-processing/post-processing steps.

@CarlosVega, Could you share the signals? Otherwise how can one try it?

Hi, here is the file for Audio 4. Thanks and sorry for my late responses. https://gofile.io/d/m7J7Cr
